# complex analysis differentiation and existence of a point?

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives

If $f(z) = z^3$
prove that there is no point $c$ on line segment $[1,i]$ 
s.t. $(f(i)-f(1)) / (i-1) = f'(c)$.

So differentiating:
$$f'(c) = 3c^2$$
$$3c^2 = (f(i)-f(1))/(i-1) = (-i-1)/(i-1) = i$$

Hence $c = \sqrt{i/3}$.

Am i doing this right? 
Could anyone also clarify what the line segment $[1,i]$ means?
Is it the diagonal line from the real axis $1$ to the Im axis $i$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be aware that $3c^2=i$ has two solutions, and you need to show that neither one is on the line segment from $[1,i]$.

Lines in the complex plane are usually described in terms of a parametric equation. For any two distinct complex numbers $a$ and $b$, the line through both  is parameterized as

$$a+(b-a)t=(1-t)a+bt, t\in\Bbb R$$.

Note that for $t=0$, we get $a$, and for $t=1$ we get $b$. So, do this for $a=1$ and $b=i$.
As you say, this is the diagonal line from the point $1$ on the real axis to $i$ in the imaginary axis.

Comment: thanks tim. buy could you help me with defining the segment $[1, i]? is this simply the segment from Imaginary i and Real 1? ie. diagonal line?

Comment: sure, I'll add to my answer

Comment: hey tim! im having troubles with your parametrization formula. if a=1 and b=i, i would get t=t. shouldn't I expect an equation of a line? thanks again!

Comment: yes, but it won't look like the usual equation you see for a line in $\Bbb R^2$  In fact, it's not an equation, it's a function $l:\Bbb R\to\Bbb C$. $l(t)=(1-t)+it$ in our example. The line is the image of $\Bbb R$ under this map.